# PyCrypto AES decryption weirdness - python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, aes, pkcs#7

I'm encrypting files with AES using PyCrypto, but when I decrypt them they have garbage characters at the head of the file. Here's a stripped down example that encrypts a text file of Moby Dick and then attempts to decrypt it:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from os import urandom

key = urandom(32)
iv = urandom(16)
aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

def encrypt_data(chunk):
    padding = AES.block_size
    if len(chunk):
        padding = AES.block_size - (len(chunk) % AES.block_size)
    return aes.encrypt(chunk + chr(padding)*padding)

with open('melville-moby-106.txt', 'r') as infile:
    with open('/tmp/test.tmp', 'w') as outfile:
        chunk = infile.read()
        while chunk:
            outfile.write(encrypt_data(chunk))
            chunk = infile.read()


with open('/tmp/test.tmp', 'r') as infile:
    with open('melville-moby-106.txt.new', 'w') as outfile:
        chunk = infile.read()
        while chunk:
            data = aes.decrypt(chunk)
            data = data[0:-ord(data[-1])]
            outfile.write(data)
            chunk = infile.read()
```

After I've run the script, I have these files:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 brian  brian  1223687 Dec 23 15:11 melville-moby-106.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 brian  brian  1223687 Dec 23 15:40 melville-moby-106.txt.new
-rw-rw-r--  1 brian  brian  1223696 Dec 23 15:40 test.tmp
```

The size looks right, but the checksums don't match:

```
96e829710ef8966d6eaef34b439cae6b  melville-moby-106.txt
94b94e495d449dad919083029a66b675  melville-moby-106.txt.new
```

If I look at the files, here's what I see:

```
$ head -n 1 melville-moby-106.txt
c                                      1851

$ head -n 1 melville-moby-106.txt.new 
Z�x#8i���[��`j�6                       1851
```

The rest of the file's contents look OK.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The AESCipher, `aes`, holds state which is mutated by the string it encrypts --
after all, the last encrypted block is used to encrypt the next block.  So to
decrypt, you need to reset the AESCipher with the same `iv` initialization value
as it started with.